# C++ expression SFINAE and ostream manipulators

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I am trying to learn how to use SFINAE.
For practice purposes, I was trying to make an `std::ostream` wrapper in order to make a custom formatter.

Here is my SFINAE and custom output class.

```
// Tester
template <class O>
struct is_ostreamable {
    template <class T>
    static auto check(T t) -> decltype(std::declval<std::ostream &>() << t, std::true_type());
    template <class>
    static auto check(...) -> std::false_type;

  public:
    static constexpr bool value{std::is_same_v<decltype(check<O>(0)), std::true_type>};
};

// Custom class
struct CustomOutput {
    // Constructor etc...
    CustomOutput(std::ostream &os = std::cout) : os{os} {}
    std::ostream &os;

    // Problematic template function
    template <class O, class = std::enable_if_t<is_ostreamable<O>::value>>
    CustomOutput &operator<<(O o) {
        os << o;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

It words perfectly to not enable the template for `struct` or `class` that cannot be printed via `operator<<`.
However, with this SFINAE, ostream manipulators are not working... And I can't figure out why.

The error, and my expectations:

```
int main(void){
    CustomOutput{} << "hi"; // Fine

    std::vector<int> vec;
    // CustomOutput{} << vec; // Error. Expected

    CustomOutput{} << std::endl; // Error. WHY?
}
```

Maybe I missed something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide fully working example. Your `CustomOutput` class is missing some parts currently

Comment: @NutCracker Sorry about that. I added the constructor and member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, fix your `ostreamable` class.  Currently, your class requires `T` to be copy-constructible from `0`.  This is not the case for many classes.  It should use `std::declval` to create the value instead:

```
template <class O>
struct is_ostreamable {
    template <class T>
    static auto check(int) -> decltype(std::declval<std::ostream &>() << std::declval<T>(), std::true_type());
    template <class>
    static auto check(...) -> std::false_type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value{std::is_same_v<decltype(check<O>(0)), std::true_type>};
};
```

Two changes are made here:

- The operand to `decltype` uses `std::declval<T>()` to create the object of type `T`.  `std::declval<T>` is an (intentionally undefined) function template that generates an object of type `T` when used in an unevaluated operand (such as that to `decltype`, or `sizeof`, `noexcept` operator, etc.) without dependence on a specific construction signature (copy-construction from `0` in your case).
- The parameter to `check` is replaced with `int`.  The initializer of the `value` variable calls `check` with the argument `0`, so this `int` parameter ensures that `(int)` ranks higher than `(...)` in overload resolution, so that the `true_type` overload gets chosen when possible.

---

You need to provide a special overload for function-style manipulators (`std::endl`, `std::flush`, etc.):

```
using manip = std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&);

CustomOutput& operator<<(manip m) {
    os << m;
    return *this;
}
```

There is, unfortunately, no way to make the generic template version support this feature.  This is because [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function template:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl(td::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os);
```

For a function template to be used, the appropriate template arguments have to be determined.  It is not possible to deduce the type-template parameter `T` as a generic template.

Anyway, this is probably the only special overload you are going to need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to make `std::endl` work this way. However, things like `std::setprecision(int)` does not work. My goal with this is to create a custom formatter that supports user defined classes as well. Meaning, I just have to add a few overloads to `operator<<`. Is it better to inherit `std::ostream` in that case? I'm also still learning when it is appropriate to use templates.

Comment: @funnypigrun Your ostreamable class is broken.  I'll update the answer to address this in a minute. "Regular" manipulators like `std::setprecision` don't need special treatment.

Comment: Oh. Let me make sure I under stand this correctly. So in my code, I wrote `check(T t)` taking `t` as a formal argument. And this caused the function to require a copy when evaluating `std::declval<T>()` later in that line?

Comment: @funnypigrun Your function took `T t` as argument, and when calling it you wrote `check<O>(0)` passing `0` as an argument. That means it would only work if `O` has a constructor accepting `0` as argument or if `0` is convertiable to a `O` or if `O` is `int`.

Comment: @funnypigrun super is right. I've updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is already an accepted answer but I would like to mention a bit prettier C++20 way of doing the same thing by using concepts:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

using OManipulator= std::ostream&(&)(std::ostream &);

template <typename T>
concept OStreamable = requires(T t) {
    std::declval<std::ostream&>() << t;
};

struct CustomOutput {
    std::ostream &os;

    CustomOutput(std::ostream &os = std::cout)
        : os{os}
    {}

    template <typename T> requires OStreamable<T>
    CustomOutput& operator<<(T out) {
        os << out;
        return *this;
    }

    CustomOutput& operator<<(OManipulator out) {
        os << out;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(void){
    CustomOutput{} << "hello";
    CustomOutput{} << std::endl;
    CustomOutput{} << "world";
}
```

Basically, in C++20, problem with manipulators needs to be solved in the same way as pre-C++20, by providing a special overload for them.